# Hibernate Tools 4.0.0 Detect many-to-many tables NOT working with MySQL Db

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many, one-to-many, hibernate-tools

I am using Hibernate Tools to reverse engineer from a MySQL 5.5.27 using STS 2.9.2 and Hibernate Tools 4.0.0.

It generates the POJO classes correctly, but is ***NOT*** picking up on the foreign key relationships defined across the tables (i.e. no sets nor relationships created ***at all!***).

Any idea from your experience whether this tool works with MySQL or what I am doing wrong?

Thanks,

Bob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I got it work at last!

The problem was, as with all things of a technical nature both simple and profound.

In a word: **CaseSensitive**

I had created my tables with capitaliZatioN (i.e. Person, Phone) and I used the MySQL Workbench to create the foreign keys and they looked like this:

CONSTRAINT `FK_Phone_Person` FOREIGN KEY (`person_id`) REFERENCES `Person` (`person_id`)

***instead of***

CONSTRAINT `FK_Phone_Person` FOREIGN KEY (`person_id`) REFERENCES `person` (`person_id`)

Notice the capitalization.

*SOO* happy after spending a lot of blood, sweat and tears trying to get that damn thing to work when all along the ***case*** was the problem!

Comment: The same is for me - I had all in capital cases and reverse engineering did not produce one-to-many. Switching all to the lower case helped

Answer (score 1):

many times the default engine of mysql also causes this issue i,e if the default engine through which the tables are create is "MyISAM" then please change it to "InnoDB"; the query to change is **ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE = InnoDB;**, hope this works :)

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that the reverse engineering tool needs specific constraints to work, if you have @OneToMany relationships they must have an intermediary table with the ids of both tables and the constraint that you cannot have null values nor orphan rows.

Also the tables will need to be named accordingly to your entities and intermediary tables must be named like `owning_entity_entity2` to work.